# Automatic trimming items/document shown by all list view webparts

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013

I would like to achieve something similar to InstanceID=date injected into url on meeting web. Then only documents in date folder or items having specified instanceID field value are displayed by all list view webparts on web site.

I need to have something like that on regular web. Is there any possibility to achieve it (reuse InstanceID somehow, other solution)?

/Bartek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this a lot in 2010 but not in 2013 yet but I am sure it will be the same.

You can add a parameter to web parts in SPD and define it to come from the Query String.  You then filter your web parts by that parameter.  You need to do this for each web part.

Now you can call your page using your parameter in the query string  eg

```
http://site/page.aspx?param=2013
```

You will need to make sure all of the lists/libraries have a common column that you can filter against.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Can it be done programmatically?

Comment: I am no developer so will have to leave that response for somebody else.

Comment: Found a way to do it programatically:
...
[code]
webPart.ParameterBindings += "\r\n <ParameterBinding Name=\"MyInstanceID\" Location=\"QueryString(MyInstanceID)\"/>";
webPart.View.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"MyInstanceID\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">{MyInstanceID}</Value></Eq></Where>";
webPart.View.Update();
limitedWebPartManager.SaveChanges(webPart);
...
[/code]